# Is it possible to parse a C# Delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, predicate

I'd like to be able to parse a Predicate and see the properties that have been set and the values to which they've been set. Is this possible?

For example, given a predicate of Person, I'd like to be able to see the expressions provided, as in:

```
Id > 5
```

or

```
Name = "Will"
```

etc.

I've been toying with different things, but I don't think I'm on the right path and I can't find an example. I did find this: [Convert Predicate<T> to Expression<Func<T, bool>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802269/convert-predicatet-to-expressionfunct-bool) but the responders seemed to strongly discourage this approach. Anyone have any thoughts on this?

For the record, I'm trying to convert the predicate to an inline SQL WHERE clause.

```
internal class Parser
{
    private IEnumerable<Person> people;
    public Parser(params Person[] people)
    {
        this.people = new List<Person>(people);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> Parse(Predicate<Person> predicate)
    {
        //IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        //IFormatterConverter converter = new FormatterConverter();
        //SerializationInfo info = new(typeof(Person), converter);
        //StreamingContext streamingContext = new StreamingContext();
        //predicate.GetObjectData(info, streamingContext);

        var invocationList = predicate.GetInvocationList();

        return Enumerable.Empty<Person>();
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, your actual question is "is it possible to parse a delegate" since a `Predicate<T>` is declared as `public delegate bool Predicate<in T>(T obj);`

Comment: @Llama Thanks. I updated the title.

Comment: I think your biggest issue is what a lambda expression becomes when your code gets compiled. See [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwCwG5nJQDMmM6AwugN7Lp2YlTboCyAFAJTW328AqAUwDOAFzYAbdAF4AfOnEA6cgHsArgDsR6OQFYO+JLwC+POqYaZmg0WwAKAJwHAAlgGMAhiIEAeADLPRbwBlEXtndQBzGTkAB0cXDy8OcxpDehMkIyA==) - `l => l.Count > 5` has become a method: `internal bool <M>b__0_0(List<string> l)`

Comment: Yeah, that's not encouraging, is it? I have another solution to this problem (a custom class in place of the delegate), but I was hopeful that it might be possible to parse the predicate and extract out the elements being queried.

Comment: You can't parse a delegate, but you can parse an expression, that's what tools like Entity Framework and LINQ 2 SQL do. The Expression class let's you look inside. You can declare and initialize an Expression and then go to town. There is (or was, haven't looked in a while) a 12 or 13 part blog series on how to create a LINQ provider. I looked at it a long time ago and it was daunting

Comment: @Flydog57 Assuming I'm going to pursue this idea, are you suggesting that I try to convert the delegate to an expression or pass an expression into the method?

Comment: @Vic You would need to pass an expression to the method. The code you found for converting a predicate to an expression simply makes a call to the delegate method, so it wouldn't help you. Accepting an `Expression<Predicate<T>>` actually produces an expression tree when compiled: [example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBkCWAdgI7YCiAHgA4BOApgM4P4D2hDA3MmpnACxck3AMyYY6AMLoA3snTzMoqH3QBZABQBKGXIV6AKowAu6gDboAvAD50p7BJYBXQkfQ2ArJsF6Avrvn+ipgqhgwmlLSMzGwAPAAK9MD4AMYAhkZ0MQRhMQDKRjREAOZWpeiRSWkZmoGySL7IPkA=)

Comment: Instead of something like `Func<int, bool> pred = num => num%2==0;` you want to create an `Expression<Func<int, bool>>` you may find _Predicate Builder_ (and related tools and source) useful